# Boolean operations on large sets of rectangles

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 2d, spatial, shapes

I have two long lists of 'rectangles' in (X1,Y1,X2,Y2) format, and I wish to perform boolean operations (AND, OR, ANDNOT) on these lists. I looked at some of the common clipping algorithms (Weiler-Atherton, Vatti and others), but they seem to be too general-purpose (all of them handle polygons with arbitrarily oriented edges). I am not too keen on bitmap-based algos either, as the tolerance for these boolean shapes is very small compared to their sizes.

Please recommend any algorithms for my use-case. My focus is primarily on minimizing runtime.

Thanks!

EDIT - A brute-force boolean operation on two long lists of rectangles is an O(n^2) operation. I am reasonably confident that, given the right data structure and algorithm, we can bring it down to at most O(nlogn).

EDIT2 - The result is another long list of rectangles (non-intersecting, but possibly touching). For instance, if my input lists are {{(0, 0), (2,2)}} and {{(1, 1), (3, 3)}}, and the intended boolean operation is OR, then my output should be {{(0, 0), (2, 1)}, {(0, 1), (3, 2)}, {(1, 2), (3, 3)}}.

Comment: Intersecting rectangles against each other is very easy, as easy as with intervals. But what exactly *is* your use case? You've only (roughly) described what you want, not why or in what context.

Comment: Intersection (and) is easy, the result will be a rectangle if they are all intersecting. But the area covered by all rectangles (or) has probably some crazy shape. If you want to return a list of non-intersecting rectangles, then two intersecting rectangles would have to be split into 3 new ones.

Comment: @harold, no doubt it is easy, but a brute-force boolean operation of two long lists of rectangles is O(n^2). I can definitely imagine that there would be O(nlogn) or even faster algorithms. I want this for a very general case - that is, the result is another (potentially very long) list of rectangles.

Comment: @maraca, precisely. The output shape will be a 'crazy' shape, but it can still be written as a list of rectangles (non-intersecting). I am looking for an algo to find this crazy shape. Also, even if the rectangles are intersecting, the output can still be a non-rectangular polygon. Look at the example I have described in the question. The two lists have intersecting rectangles, but the output is still a crazy shape.